# Aftereffects and Photoshops ui do not work in vmwere 7 in a maverick VM

Tags: virtual-machine, adobe-photoshop, osx-mavericks, vmware-fusion, adobe-after-effects

so first off i will explane I set up a VM of mavericks in VMwere fusion because some of my software will not work in Yosemite and I want to upgrade so I created a legacy VM in VMwere fusion 7.

However after instilling Adobe CS5 on the vm some of the adobe programs UI will not work. for example in Photoshop when u select a menu the menu items wont highlighted when being hovered over by the mouse. [Photoshop glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swyu3.png)

and in aftereffects  I can not use any of the input boxes or controls. for example here I can not change anything here. [i can not change anything here](http://bencawley.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1)
the cursor will change when hovering over them but clicking them is like clicking a screenshot. it dose nothing I cant type in to them or do anything.

now its not all the adobe programs. Illustrator and Indesing work fine.
anyway i am told its VMWere doing it but I don't have a clue how to fix it. I have instilled vmtools but that has not fixed it. so please it would be great if you guys could help me and thank you.